# How to set values in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm creating an `ArrayList` of type `B`:

```
ArrayList<B> cert= new ArrayList<B>;
B a  = util.getCerts(path).iterator().next();
this.cert.add(a);
this.certNode(certs);
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception when I try to set the value:

```
void certNode(ArrayList<B> certResp) 
{       
    ArrayList<RespNode> exp = new ArrayList<RespNode>();
    for (int i = 0; i< certResp.size(); i++) {  
        exp.get(i).setxxx(certResp.get(i).getxxx());
        exp.get(i).setxxx(certResp.get(i).getxxx().toString());     
    }
 }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Don't add value with .get(i).set. To set a value you already need a value at this position. What you want to do is to ADD a value. Just replace with exp.add(new RespNodde(certResp.get(i).getxxx()));

Comment: Not sure whether this is your problem, but since it has not yet been mentioned in any of the answers: Note that you _create_ `cert`, but then you try to _use_ `this.cert`, which is not the same!

Answer (score 2):

Since you just created the ArrayList instance `exp`, `exp.get(i)` doesn't exist, so you can't call `exp.get(i).setxxx(...)`.

EDIT :

Try :

```
void certNode(ArrayList<B> certResp) {      
    ArrayList<RespNode> exp = new ArrayList<RespNode>();
    for (int i = 0; i< certResp.size(); i++) {  
        exp.add(certResp.get(i).getxxx());     
    }
 }
```

It's hard to be sure without knowing the return value of `certResp.get(i).getxxx()`, but if it returns `RespNode`, the code above would add that `RespNode` instance of the list.

Comment: Is there any other way i can set the values

Comment: Wouldn't the exception in the case of an empty List be `IndexOutOfBoundException`?

Comment: exp.addAll() is not possible first arrayList is ArrayList<B> and second list is of type ArrayList<RespNode>

Comment: Again you are setting value in same list ArrayList<B> and not other one'

Comment: exp.addAll(certResp)-- I tried doing this but it says it is not applicable to ArrayList<>

Comment: @pals I edited the answer, since I just noticed the two array lists hold different types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here : `exp.get(i)`. `exp` is the newly created ArayList, so it's empty, so there is a `null` at index `i`

Comment: The loop is on `certResp`, which is the method's parameter and might not be empty !

Answer (score 0):

Your list 'exp' is empty. In the for-loop you get a value of null; calling a method from null will cause the NullPointerException.

You have to put values in the list before you try to access them.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating new empty ArrayList i.e []

```
exp.get(i)
```

gives you null

Instead you can use add method of ArrayList

```
void certNode(ArrayList<B> certResp) {
    //Here new empty list is created i.e exp=[] //no elements inside
    //Suppose your certResp=[B@12312,B@123834] i.e two B class objects     
    ArrayList<RespNode> exp = new ArrayList<RespNode>();

    for (int i = 0; i< certResp.size(); i++) {  //Size of certResp=2 as it contains 2 B objects  
        RespNode res=new RespNode(); //Create a RespNode class as you want to add of certResp ArrayList<RespNode>

        res.setxxx(certResp.get(i)); //Take value of xxx method of certResp.get(i) i.e B object xxx method and set into res.setXXX or RespNode class

        exp.add(res); //add res object into ArrayList
    }
 }
```

Comment: I added comments for particular lines

Comment: Thanks Shoaib! and also can i change the return type of this ArrayList<RespNode>

Comment: I mean instead of void certNode i want to return this as ArrayList<RespNode>

Comment: Depends on your class what you are using. http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/how-to-use-generic-arraylist.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    void certNode(ArrayList<B> certResp) {      
        ArrayList<RespNode> exp = new ArrayList<RespNode>();
        for (int i = 0; i< certResp.size(); i++) {  
            exp.add(new RespNode()); // <----- 
            exp.get(i).setxxx(certResp.get(i).getxxx());
            exp.get(i).setxxx(certResp.get(i).getxxx().toString());     
        }
     }
```

btw you can improve syntax

```
    void certNode(ArrayList<B> certResp) {      
        ArrayList<RespNode> exp = new ArrayList<RespNode>();
        for (B b : certResp){
          RespNode resp = new RespNode();
          resp.setxxxx(b.getxxxx());
          exp.add(resp);
        }
     }
```